# How to set boundingbox for a layer?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I've created a Joystick class based on a CCNode with the following characteristics.

```
-(id)initWithLocation:(CGPoint)l
{
  if (self = [super init])
  {
    self.position = l;
    self.isRelativeAnchorPoint = NO;
    _background = [[[CCSprite alloc] initWithSpriteFrameName:@"JoystickBackground.png"] autorelease];
    [self addChild:_background];
    _stick = [[[CCSprite alloc] initWithSpriteFrameName:@"smallWhiteCircle.png"] autorelease];
    [self addChild:_stick];
    self.contentSize = _background.contentSize;
    _radius = self.contentSize.height / 2;    
  }

  return self;
}
```

The problem is that joystick.boundingbox.origin returns the mid point of the joystick. Is shall return the lower left corner. Is it possible to configure this for a layer (i.e. when self.isRelativeAnchorPoint = NO)?

I've solved this by overriding boundingbox with the following function

```
-(CGRect)boundingBox
{
  CGRect r;
  r.size = [self contentSize];
  CGPoint p = self.position;
  r.origin = ccp(p.x - r.size.width / 2, p.y - r.size.height / 2);

  return r;
}
```

but is there a better way?

I want _stick to be at position ccp(0. 0). That's the reason why I want to use a layer instead of an ordinary CCNode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
-(CGRect) boundingBox 
{
    if(isRelativeAnchorPoint)
      return [super boundingBox];

    CGRect sprRect = CGRectMake(
                                self.position.x - self.contentSize.width*self.anchorPoint.x,
                                self.position.y - self.contentSize.height*self.anchorPoint.y,
                                self.contentSize.width,
                                self.contentSize.height
                                );

    return sprRect;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Guru, but I guess I was a bit unclear in my question. Do I need to override the boundingbox method? I don't need to override it when isRelativeAnchorPoint==YES. But maybe I have to do an override when it's set to NO?

Comment: Thanks. My question was actually if I need to override the boundingbox method in my class, or if it was possible to make the inherited boundingbox method to work by just adjusting some attribute, but I interprete your answer as a YES I have to override it.